# cost calculator using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a cost calculator using JavaScript.
I have two button in my code; clear and calculate and both work fine for the first time.
However when I select different drop down menu and try to calculate again, it doesn't recalculate but same number or blank fields stay in the table.

How do I make it to recalculate? and is it possible to do this without clear button?

```js
var settingValue;
    
    function clearForm(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
    
    
    function settingValue() {
      var payment;
      var copayPerc = document.getElementById("copayPerc").value;
      settingValue = document.getElementById("Setting").value;
       payment=medicarePaymentCal(settingValue); 
       document.getElementById("medipayment").value = payment;
       document.getElementById("adj").value=seqAdjCal(payment);
      document.getElementById("net").value=payment+seqAdjCal(payment);
       
       document.getElementById("copay").value=payment*0.2;
       document.getElementById("actualCopay").value=payment*0.2*copayPerc;
       totalProductCost();
    }
    
    
    function medicarePaymentCal(value1) {
      var result;
      if (value1 == "Office") {
        return 1411.21;
      } else if (value1="HOPD") {
        return 500;
      }
     }
     
     function seqAdjCal(val){
      return -(0.02*(0.8*val));
     
     }
     
     function totalProductCost(){
      var applications=document.getElementById("applications").value;
      var productCost=document.getElementById("productCost").value;
      var total=applications*productCost;
      document.getElementById("totalProductCost").value = total;
     }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>Setting : </td>
      <td><select id="Setting">
        <option value="Office">Office</option>
        <option value="HOPD">HOPD</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Facility : </td>
      <td><select id="Facility">
        <option value="100015">Mount Sinai, 123 Main Street, New York</option>
        <option value="100016">NYU Medical, 25 North Broadway, New York</option>
      </select></td>
    
      <tr>
          <td>Product Size : </td>
          <td>
            <100sq cm</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
          <td>Number of DFU patients :</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Patient co-pay % (based on wage adj.rate) : </td>
          <td>0.2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Co-Pay percent actuallly collected : </td>
          <td><input id="copayPerc" type="number" value="0.75"></td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" onclick="clearForm();">
     </td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" id="button" value="calculate" onclick="settingValue();">
          </td>
        </tr>
    
    </table>
    
    
      <table border=1>
      
    
        <tr>
          <td>Medicare Payment :</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" id="medipayment">
          </td>
        </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Sequestration Adjustment (-2%) : </td>
     <td> <input type="number" id="adj"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Medicare Payment Net of Seq. : </td>
     <td> <input type="number" id="net"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Projected Patient Co-Pay : </td>
     <td> <input type="number" id="copay"> </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Actual Co-Pay Amount Collected : </td>
     <td> <input type="number" id="actualCopay"> </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>No. of applications per Episode : </td>
     <td> <input type="number" id="applications" value="1"> </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Product cost per treatment : </td>
     <td> <input type="number" id="productCost" value="1125"> </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>Total product cost per episode : </td>
     <td> <input type="number" id="totalProductCost"> </td>
    </tr>
    
    
    
      </table>
    
    </form>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It look like you have an error. You're using the same name `settingValue` for both, a variable and a function. The first run works as the function is defined at the end. But the code run and change the function with the variable value. Just rename the variable or the function an try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var settingValue` has same name as `function settingValue`.

Just rename one and should work:

```js
  var settingValue;

  function clearForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }


  function funcSettingValue() {
    var payment;
    var copayPerc = document.getElementById("copayPerc").value;
    settingValue = document.getElementById("Setting").value;
    payment = medicarePaymentCal(settingValue);
    document.getElementById("medipayment").value = payment;
    document.getElementById("adj").value = seqAdjCal(payment);
    document.getElementById("net").value = payment + seqAdjCal(payment);

    document.getElementById("copay").value = payment * 0.2;
    document.getElementById("actualCopay").value = payment * 0.2 * copayPerc;
    totalProductCost();
  }


  function medicarePaymentCal(value1) {
    var result;
    if (value1 == "Office") {
      return 1411.21;
    } else if (value1 = "HOPD") {
      return 500;
    }
  }

  function seqAdjCal(val) {
    return -(0.02 * (0.8 * val));

  }

  function totalProductCost() {
    var applications = document.getElementById("applications").value;
    var productCost = document.getElementById("productCost").value;
    var total = applications * productCost;
    document.getElementById("totalProductCost").value = total;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<form method="post" id="myForm">
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>Setting :</td>
      <td>
        <select id="Setting">
          <option value="Office">Office</option>
          <option value="HOPD">HOPD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Facility :</td>
      <td>
        <select id="Facility">
          <option value="100015">Mount Sinai, 123 Main Street, New York</option>
          <option value="100016">NYU Medical, 25 North Broadway, New York</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <tr>
        <td>Product Size :</td>
        <td>
          <100sq cm</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Number of DFU patients :</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patient co-pay % (based on wage adj.rate) :</td>
        <td>0.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Co-Pay percent actuallly collected :</td>
        <td>
          <input id="copayPerc" type="number" value="0.75">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" onclick="clearForm();">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="button" value="calculate" onclick="funcSettingValue();">
        </td>
      </tr>

  </table>


  <table border=1>


    <tr>
      <td>Medicare Payment :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="medipayment">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Sequestration Adjustment (-2%) :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="adj">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Medicare Payment Net of Seq. :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="net">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Projected Patient Co-Pay :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="copay">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Actual Co-Pay Amount Collected :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="actualCopay">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>No. of applications per Episode :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="applications" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Product cost per treatment :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="productCost" value="1125">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Total product cost per episode :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="totalProductCost">
      </td>
    </tr>



  </table>

</form>

</html>
```

Comment: It is also possible just to add `var` before the line that sets the variable settingValue. This prevents the variable from having global scope and clobbering the function.